# Debugging jQuery event triggers in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Is there a tool that lets me debug exactly when a jQuery event is bound to an element on the DOM in a Rails application?  I have an app with the following in one of my javascript files:

```
   $("a").click(function(event){
     alert("hot stuff");
     console.log('Testing console');
   });
```

The alert shows up once when I click a link on most pages but twice when I click a link on the homepage.  It looks like something is binding the same event to a link twice on the homepage only, but how can I confirm and fix this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955433/how-to-debug-your-jquery-script or further look into the `debugger` keyword you can put in to debug the code, Your Dom might have parent and child `a` tag that why 2 triggers look for API JQ: `stopPropogation` rest should help, `:)`